# Is it necessary to use “the” before using verb+“ing” in specific contexts?

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles, gerunds, syntactic-analysis, zero-article

I am confused with whether it is necessary to use *the* before verbs in certain contexts. Like:

1. **The** milking of a cow is not a painful process at all like you think.
2. I am afraid it has never been explained how **the** whole dream-sharing thing works in *Inception*.

So in both cases above, can we exclude the *the* before those verb+*ing* constructs?

Comment: I think the question needs a better title. I request anybody to feel free to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The milking of a cow is not a painful process at all like you think* is verbose and ungrammatical. *Process* is almost always an expendable word. It would be better expressed as:

> Milking a cow is not as painful as you think.

*I am afraid it has never been explained how does the whole dream sharing works in "Inception"* is also verbose, ungrammatical, and a bit awkward. "I am afraid" is an empty expression unless  you're contradicting someone's claim that dream sharing was explained. It would be better expressed as:

> How dream sharing works is never explained in (the movie) *Inception*.

Comment: What about using "the" before the verbs? I think that is my main question. I request you to elaborate on it briefly! Otherwise your answer on their usage is awesome!

Comment: _Milking_ and _sharing_ are nouns (gerunds), not verbs. Verbs don't take the definite article, but nouns do.

Comment: Oooo..Did not know that! So when we use _gerunds_, we need to use _the_, correct?

Comment: No, you don't **need** to use _the_. I didn't use it in either sentence I suggested. If you were to say "I have to do **the milking** now, so I'll see you later", you need _the_. You could also say "I have **to milk** the cows now".

Comment: @Robusto: Thank you. I do this not for rewards from others but for the pleasure it gives me to express my opinions, however outrageous they may be one some occasions. <:-O

Comment: I think Robusto meant the OP.

Comment: @Kris: Maybe so. But ambiguity has its virtues. If only to illustrate its perils.

Comment: @Robusto, How can I leave the answer until I get it properly? :O I am astonished at your comment!